Tailwind CSS: Inconsistent Behavior with Dynamic Color Classes
Issue Description
When using Tailwind CSS with dynamic color classes, certain hex color codes work perfectly while others fail to apply, despite using identical syntax and implementation.
Working Example

cardColor="[#008ffb]"  // Works perfectly for both text-[#008ffb] and bg-[#008ffb]
cardColor="[#ff9920]"  // Works perfectly
cardColor="[#d83b34]"  // Works perfectly
Non-Working Example
cardColor="[#FBCFE8]"  // Doesn't work
cardColor="[#E0F2FE]"  // Doesn't work
cardColor="[#1b2559]"  // Doesn't work
cardColor="[#111c44]"  // Doesn't work

Implementation
Component usage
    <CustomCard 
          title="Saved Venues"
          cardColor="[#008ffb]"
          addclassName=""
    >

Component implementation
   <h2 className={`text-${cardColor} text-shadow-sm text-3xl font-mono`}>
          {title} 
    </h2>
    <div className={`h-[1px] -mt-1 mb-4 bg-${cardColor}`}>
        &nbsp;
    </div>

Observations

The syntax is identical for all color codes
Some colors work for both text and background
Some colors work partially (e.g., #d1f5f0 worked for background but not text)
Case sensitivity doesn't affect the outcome
The colors that work are already being used elsewhere in the project
The issue persists even when the non-working colors are used directly in other Tailwind classes in the same project

Questions

Why do some hex colors work perfectly while others fail when using identical syntax?
Is there a pattern to which colors work and which don't?
Could this be related to how Tailwind processes dynamic class names with arbitrary values?
Is there a difference in how Tailwind handles color codes in its internal color processing versus arbitrary values?

Environment

Next.js
Tailwind CSS
TypeScript
shadcn/ui components

Workaround
Currently using known working colors (e.g., #008ffb) as a reliable solution, but would like to understand the root cause of this behavior.

You should read this, Safelisting classes first.

You can manually whitelist the specific dynamic classes you're using by adding them to your safelist in tailwind.config.js
module.exports = {
  content: [
    './src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}',
  ],
  safelist: [
    'text-[#FBCFE8]',
    'bg-[#FBCFE8]',
    'text-[#E0F2FE]',
    'bg-[#E0F2FE]',
    'text-[#1b2559]',
    'bg-[#1b2559]',
    'text-[#111c44]',
    'bg-[#111c44]',
  ],
};

